# Problems in creating a json file with nested data

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to create a nested json on databricks.

This is the code I used:

```
data = df.groupby('plant', 'at').agg(
F.collect_list(
  F.struct(F.col("product"),F.col("quantity"))
).alias('products'))
```

I need to get

```
{"plant":"plant_x","at":"2019-06-12T13:54:29.947Z","products":[{"product":"product1","quantity":39}, {""product"":""product2"",""quantity"":2} ]
```

but instead I get something different with "/" and strange [] {}, and doubled ""

```
plant_x,2019-06-13T13:23:12.539+0000,"[{""product"":""product1"",""quantity"":39},{""product"":""product2"",""quantity"":2} ]"
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: There is a to map function in latest spart that should do the trick

Comment: solved adding     coalesce(1).write.format('json').option("quote", "\u0000").mode("overwrite").save(path_folder)